# В старых снимках (commits) видны добавленные позже файлы и подаются Гитом как «Unversioned Files»

Tags: git, gitignore

Вёл историю, постепенно добавляя в `.gitignore` файлы по мере их появления.
Позже заметил, что, откатившись к старым снимкам, я вижу в них как неотслеживаемые те файлы, которые были добавлены намного позже.
Сначала подумал, что причина в бывшей ранее ошибочной записи `.gitignore` в файле «.gitignore», которая позже была убрана во всей истории.
Сделал полную перезапись (rebase) истории, останавливаясь на каждом снимке и проверяя отсутствие лишнего и соответствие записей в `.gitignore` содержимому снимка. Но снова откатившись по истории, получаю в первом снимке красным цветом весь букет файлов из последнего, но помеченных как «Unversioned Files». Так же некоторые другие файлы помечены как `ignored, tracked with git`.
Использую ИСР «PHPStorm».
Как навести порядок, чтобы в старых снимках не отображались добавленные позже игнорируемые файлы? Или это нормальное поведение?

Comment: раз уж перезаписываете историю, так поместите текущую версию `.gitignore` в самое её начало.

Comment: цитата из стандартных причин закрытия: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). // и, кстати, не примешивайте в вопрос про *git* вопрос про *phpstorm*. вы ведь даже задали его отдельно.

Comment: `откатившись к старым снимкам` – как вы это делали? Если с помощью `git reset`, то логично, что файлы из более новых коммитов остались на месте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Unversioned Files" означает «неотслеживаемые» или «неверсионируемые» файлы. Они принципиально не могут быть в коммите. В эту категорию Git (команда `git status`) относит файлы, которые:

- в данный момент находятся в рабочей области проекта (т.е. на диске, в файловой системе),
- но при этом их нет в последнем коммите и они не были добавлены в индекс (командой `git add`).

## Откуда могли появиться эти файлы

Возможно несколько вариантов:

- У вас были неотслеживаемые (untracked) файлы и до того, как вы переключились на старый коммит. Они как были, так и остались неотслеживаемыми.
- Вы использовали команду `git reset` и поэтому Git, переходя на старый коммит, не поменял состояние рабочей области. Остались файлы из более нового коммита. В старом коммите про них ещё ничего не известно.

## Демонстрация

Инициализируем репозиторий в новой папке

```
mkdir unversioned-files
cd unversioned-files
git init
```

В первый коммит сохраним файл `а`

```
touch a
git add a
git commit -m'add a'
```

Во второй коммит сохраним файл `b`

```
touch b
git add b
git commit -m'add b'
```

Создадим ещё один файл, но добавлять не будем

```
touch c
```

Посмотрим на лог (у вас будут другие хеши)

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate

* 2810197 (HEAD -> master) add b
* db40c3c add a
```

Посмотрим на состояние

```
git status 
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    c
```

Видно, что файл `c` попал в категорию Untracked files.
Он ещё ни разу не добавлялся в коммит.

Теперь переключим репозиторий на предыдущий коммит,
а рабочую область (файлы) оставим неизменной

```
git reset HEAD^

# результат
git status

On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    b
    c
```

Файл `b` добавлялся только во втором коммите, а репозиторий переключен на первый.
Первый коммит не знает ничего про файлы `b` и `c`.
Поэтому оба файла — Untracked.

## Как Git определяет untracked файлы

Небольшой экскурс в анатомию для тех, кому интересно.

Каждый коммит хранит информацию о дереве файлов и папок, которые в этом коммите сохранены. Для каждого файла есть ссылка на архив с его содержимым. Посмотреть можно так:

```
$ git cat-file HEAD -p                                                                                                           
tree 7394b8cc9ca916312a79ce8078c34b49b1617718
...
```

Возьмем хеш из tree, убедимся что этот объект действительно дерево:

```
git cat-file 7394b8cc9ca916312a79ce8078c34b49b1617718 -t                                                                                                           
tree
```

Что внутри?

```
$ git cat-file 7394b8cc9ca916312a79ce8078c34b49b1617718 -p                                                                                                           
100644 blob 3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad    readme.md
```

Команда `git add` собирает такое же дерево для предстоящего коммита в файле `.git/index`. Посмотрим на содержимое:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 3b18e512dba79e4c8300dd08aeb37f8e728b8dad 0   readme.md
```

Видно, что там тот же файл — значит новых файлов в индекс не добавляли. У файла тот же хеш — новых версий этого файла тоже не добавляли.

Когда вы выполняете команду `git status`, происходит что-то такое:

- Git берет описание дерева файлов и папок из последнего коммита и из индекса.
- Собирает аналогичное описание дерева, которое прямо сейчас есть на диске.
- Сравнивает деревья.

Так вот, если фактически на диске файл есть, а в дереве текущего коммита и в индексе файла нет — то в выводе команды `git status` этот файл попадает в категорию `untracked`.

Для сравнения: если файла нет в последнем коммите, но его добавили в индекс, он будет обозначен как `new file`. Если наоборот, из индекса убрали (`git rm filename`), но в коммите был — то `deleted`. Если после этого вернули — то он будет одновременно `deleted` и `untracked`.

Comment: @akp `отображение неотслеживаемых файлов во всей истории — это нормально` – они вообще не часть истории, но отображение — конечно нормальное.